I'm having issue puppeteer working with my default browser
I'm trying to launch puppeteer using my default browser in mac, I was able to launch but its throwing this Error after launching and opening new page, what seems to be issue ?? please help, thanks !
CODE :
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require('path');

async function launchBrowser() {
  // Path to the default Chrome profile
  const userDataDir = path.join(
    process.env.HOME,
    'Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome'
  );

  try {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
      userDataDir: userDataDir, // Use the default Chrome profile directory
      args: [
        '--start-maximized',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--profile-directory=Default', // Use the 'Default' profile
        '--no-first-run',
      ],
      defaultViewport: null,
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'], // Hide automation flag
    });

    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/")



  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Launch error:', error);
    console.error('Chrome path:', '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome');
    console.error('User data dir:', userDataDir);
    throw error;
  }
}

launchBrowser()



Did you mean to [edit] that into the question? Please share the full error, this is just the stack trace, not the actual error message.

Hello Yes this is the Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
I want navigate to https://www.google.com/ as a test but its not working, do seem to know the problem ?

Did you try all of the 40 answers in the canonical thread, Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer?

most of those answers are for chromium, i'm using default user in chrome, thats when i encounter the error.
